# JSF no me reconoce nuevos archivos XHTML

Tags: java, xml, jsf, maven, xhtml

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web (JSF + Maven) que ingrese usuario y password (previamente implementados en el constructor de una clase Java e integrados en un ArrayList, para dar la sensación de que hay una "conexión" con una base de datos) y, tras dejarla un tiempo en stanby, hoy he vuelto a ella. 
El problema viene cuando creo nuevos archivos xhtml. Estos no muestran los atributos Java que previamente han sido almacenados.

Por ejemplo: si tu pones como usuario 'pepe', si he logradoo que en archivos xhtml anteriores se muestre vía web 'Hola don pepe', ya que ese archivo xhtml contiene la etiqueta:

```
<p>Hola don #{nombreDeLaClaseJava.usuario}</p>
```

pero si quiero que esto mismo me salga en nuevos archivos xhtml, no lo consigo. No lee la parte de la etiqueta concerniente al atributo Java, por lo que no lo muestra.

En resumen: no consigo relacionar nuevos archivos xhtml con la clase ManagedBean Java, cosa que si consigo con otros archivos xhtml anteriores.

Las etiquetas h están correctamente, así comos los getters and setters corresponientes. Utilizo Tomcat por si sirve de ayuda. También he probado a limpiar el proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Tu bean debería tener las anotaciones @ManagedBean y el scope, por ejemplo @SessionScoped. Revisa que cuando importaste las librerías para estas dos anotaciones hayas elegido estas:

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

Es posible que por error no hayas importado exactamente esas. Por eso desde el XHTML no podes ver todo lo que tenga que ver con tu bean.